# Cannot move custom graphics along with map movements, using Mapbox Android SDK

Tags: android, mapbox

I am using Mapbox Android SDK together with some custom offline maps. I have long experience from iOS, but I am a beginner with Android.

I am simply trying to show some markers on the map. Since I had problems with the Mapbox Marker class, I am instead trying to implement the markers by custom Views attached to an invisible RelativeLayout located on top of the map (this is `myMarkerOverlay` in the code). Then my intention is to move these markers by manipulating their `leftMargin` and `topMargin` while the user is scrolling/zooming/rotating the map.

The code for updating the marker positions is triggered from the `MapListener` methods `onScroll`, `onZoom` and `onRotate`.

These are the problems:

- onScroll is triggering `repositionAllMarkers` (verfied by debugging),
  but the markers are never moved on the screen.
- onZoom and onRotate are working, but only when the gesture has
  ended (i.e. the user has lift the fingers from the screen). I want the
  marker positions to be updated continuously during the gesture!

Is this a Mapbox specific problem or have I missed something important about how animation is done on Android?
(As can be seen in the code, I tried to add `theMarker.invalidate()` with no success.)

The code:

```
private void repositionAllMarkers() {

    // Get the current (variable) projection
    Projection proj = mapView.getProjection();

    // Calculate a deltaX and deltaY based on the marker icon size and anchor position
    // The screencoordinates will then be adjusted by these amounts when setting the left and
    // top margins of the markers

    float deltaXdp = - MARKER_ANCHOR_X * MARKER_WIDTH;
    float deltaYdp = - MARKER_ANCHOR_Y * MARKER_HEIGHT;

    // Convert from dp to pixels

    DisplayMetrics dm = getActivity().getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    int deltaX = Math.round(deltaXdp * dm.density);
    int deltaY = Math.round(deltaYdp * dm.density);

    // Loop through all markers

    PointF screenPoint = null;
    for(int i = 0; i < myMarkerOverlay.getChildCount(); i++) {
        MyMarker theMarker = (MyMarker) myMarkerOverlay.getChildAt(i);
        screenPoint = proj.toPixels(theMarker, screenPoint);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) theMarker.getLayoutParams();
        lp.leftMargin = Math.round(screenPoint.x) + deltaX;
        lp.topMargin = Math.round(screenPoint.y) + deltaY;

        // Try forcing a redraw of the marker
        theMarker.invalidate();
    }
}

// MapListener methods

@Override
public void onScroll(ScrollEvent event) {

    repositionAllMarkers();
}

@Override
public void onZoom(ZoomEvent event) {

    repositionAllMarkers();
}

@Override
public void onRotate(RotateEvent event) {

    repositionAllMarkers();
}
```

`MyMarker` extends `RelativeLayout` and implements the Mapbox interface `ILatLng` (i.e. it is storing its own position which can be read by `getLatitude` and `getLongitude`). All `MyMarker` instances have already been added to `myMarkerOverlay`.

Comment: I'm working on the same issue. Did you figure out something that would solve this?

Comment: Sorry, but I haven't done any work on this code since last summer, so I don't remember the details. I think that I never solved this particular problem. Probably I found some kind of workaround.